# LIBGDX font.draw() makes letters blink on PC

Tags: java, libgdx

I load Bitmapfont then try to draw it, but on PC(desktop) build screen blinks with frequecy that I can judge that backbuffer is not drawn. On Android all is fine, I don't see blinking. I simply do this:

```
SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
Bitmapfont font = new Bitmapfont();
font.setColor(Color.GREEN);
spriteBatch.begin();
font.draw(spriteBatch, "Hello world", 0, 100);
spriteBatch.end();
```

Ways to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have called that in your render method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Because, it looks like your code should work.

We figured out, that he needed to disable, because he wanted to draw the Screen on demand

"continuus rendering" https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-%26-non-continuous-rendering

Comment: good point. I did it in show() because i do some app initialization there and wanted to display message. I guess some List of messages is needed to put it in render() method and render it properly. Only way?

Comment: You need to clear your frame nearly always in the rendermethod (prefered at the start of thr render method. And in show it would be nearly useless, because show is called only once.

Comment: i disable all drawing untill initialization is done and it works, just text is blinking. :) maybe there is a way to font.draw() in both buffers...

Comment: I have identical code, it doesnt blink, show me your render method please, edit your question for this extra information

Comment: Ofcourse, please put your render method in your question, so we can analyze it.

Comment: I disabled all glClear() where they were throughout all app, show() contains only code I posted, render() is waiting for a flag to do anything and I see blinking text. When I put this code in render() blinking stops. my thought its valid to conclude that backbuffer isn't drawn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41069/discussion-between-tohaz-and-keey).